# How to replace string in a string but leave string in brackets as it is in python?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string, replace

I've tried looking but all I came across was how to replace data inside brackets.

What I've been trying to do is, convert

```
Hello Hello <Hello> hello <hello>
```

Into

```
Abc Abc <Hello> abc <hello>
```

My brain says to add > at start and < at end and use regex to only replace the strings between > < . Tho, I've little to no idea on how to use regex, I think I'll be able to do it like that if I search for it. Still, is there any other neat way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the brackets are well-formed and aren't nested, match word characters that aren't inside brackets by using negative lookahead for `[^<>]*>`.

```
input = 'Hello Hello <Hello> hello <hello>'
print(re.sub(r'\w+(?![^<>]*>)', 'Abc', input))
```

Comment: That gives what I want, tho I didn't want to change all words to same sub-string. But now I know where I should start. Thanks.